# Using shiny and plotly, how can I animate a vertical line on a time series that scrolls with the current frame of an embedded movie?

Tags: video, shiny, plotly

I am making a dashboard using R, shiny and plotly. I would like to show a video, and beneath it a plot of a time series that relates to each moment in the video. When the user plays the video, I want to show a vertical line on the plot that corresponds to current playing time on the video. In other words, it's a sort of scrolling playhead.

The code and toy data here achieves what I want, but poorly. There are two problems.

1. The line only updates about once a second. Ideally, I'd like it to move more smoothly, something like 30 frames per second to match the video.
2. As I understand plotly and shiny (ie not very well), then each time I am moving the vertical line, I am re-drawing the whole plot. With the toy data here, that may not be problem. But eventually I will be using very large data sets and doing some smoothing, so I only want to draw the time series once, and update the vertical line position by itself. There are instructions about using plotlyProxyInvoke [here](https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html#proxies)but I can't implement those ideas in my case.

I'm fairly competent in R and ggplot, but this is my first time with both shiny and plotly, so apologies if I'd missing something basic. Any suggestions very much appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(video)

data <- data.frame(t=1:45,y=sample(x=50,size = 45))

ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      video(
        "https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4",
        elementId = "video"),
      tags$p( "Duration:",
        textOutput("video_seek", container = tags$strong, inline = TRUE), "/",
        textOutput("video_duration", container = tags$strong, inline = TRUE) ),
       plotlyOutput(outputId = "sparkline")
  ) )

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$sparkline <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplotly( ggplot(data,aes(x=t,y=y))+geom_line() )
    add_segments(p,x=input$video_seek,xend=input$video_seek,y=0,yend=50,inherit = F)  })
  output$video_duration <- renderText({input$video_duration })
  output$video_seek <- renderText({ input$video_seek })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: UPDATE! OK i have solved (1) the easier problem of the playhead updating only once a second. I just had to add an option to the video object, after the elementId:  "seek_ping_rate = 33". Have left question intact in case anyone else comes across it. The harder problem (2) of only updating the vertical line bit of the plot remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `plotlyProxy` together with `plotlyProxyInvoke`.

Idea is that you make the basic plot in the `renderPlotly` function and use `plotlyProxyInvoke` to update the trace corresponding to the sparkline.

```r
library(shiny)
library(video)
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame(t = 1:45,
                   y = sample(50, size = 45))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
   output$sparkline <- renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(
         data,
         x = ~t,
         y = ~y,
         type = "scatter",
         mode = "lines"
      ) %>% 
         add_segments(x = 0, xend = 0, y = 0, yend = 50) %>%
         layout(xaxis = list(range = c(0, ceiling(req(input$video_duration)))))
   })
   
   output$video_duration <- renderText(input$video_duration)
   output$video_seek <- renderText(input$video_seek)
   
   observeEvent(input$video_seek, {
      plotlyProxy("sparkline") %>%
         plotlyProxyInvoke("restyle",
                           list(x = list(rep(input$video_seek, 2))),
                           1)

   })
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks @thothal!! Very much appreciated. I got this to work nicely, with your help. Then I broke it again by making three different lines on my plot of different colours. Eventually i figured out that I had to change that number 1 in the plotlyProxyInvoke function to 3, because I had introduced new traces into the plot. Just explaining this in case someone else runs into the same problem.